# $s_{n+1} = \sqrt{s_n+1}$ converges to $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $s_n = 1$ and for $n \geq 1$, let $s_{n+1} = \sqrt{s_n+1}$.
Given this sequence and assume that it converges. I have to prove that the limit is $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

By using the definition of limit, I tried to set $n > N\ implies\ |\sqrt{s_n+1}-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}| < \epsilon$.
But I have no idea how to simplify the expression in the absolute value and get rid of absolute value!!!
Can anyone give some hints??

Comment: Call the limit $L$. Note $L>0$. Show (using the formula for $s_n$) that $L=\sqrt {L+1}$. Solve for $L$.

Comment: I believe the first sentence should begin "Let $s_0=1$...", not $s_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are *forced* to use an $\epsilon$-$N$ calculation, here is how it could go.

Let $\tau=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$. Then
$$s_{n+1}-\tau =\sqrt{s_n+1}-\tau=\frac{s_n+1-\tau^2}{\sqrt{s_n+1}+\tau}.$$
(We multiplied "top" and "bottom" by $\sqrt{s_n+1}+\tau$.)

Now use the fact that $1-\tau^2=-\tau$, and that $\sqrt{s_n+1}+\tau \gt 1+\tau\gt 2$ to get the inequality
$$|s_{n+1}-\tau| \lt \frac{1}{2}|s_n-\tau|.\tag{1}$$
Note that $|s_1-\tau|\lt 1$. Using (1) we then obtain
$$|s_{k}-\tau|\lt \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}.$$
This estimate now can be used in a routine way to find a suitable $N$, given $\epsilon$.

**Remark:** We deliberately gave away a lot in the calculation. One can sharpen estimates to get precise information about the rate of convergence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..!! There are few parts that I dont understand!! (1). How is $1-\tau^2 = -\tau$?? (2). How is $|s_{n+1}-\tau < \frac{1}{2}|s_n-\tau| \rightarrow |s_k-\tau| < \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$?? Thanks!!

Comment: First question: $1-\tau^2=-\tau$ because $\tau$ is a solution of the equation $x^2-x-1=0$ (use the Quadratic Formula). Second question: Inequality (1) ways that the "error" goes down by a factor of at least $\frac{1}{2}$ for each iteration. Since the error at $s_1$ is $\lt 1$, the error at $s_2$ is $\lt \frac{1}{2}$, the error at $s_3$ is $\lt \frac{1}{4}$, and so on.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that it is convergent, you can use continuity of the function $\sqrt{x+1}$ to conclude
$$s:=\lim s_{n+1}=\lim\sqrt{s_n+1}=\sqrt{s+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} s_{n+1}$$